# How can I cast votes in the community moderator election?

Tags: support, moderator-election

Today, I received a message in my inbox notifying me to cast my vote in the 2024 community moderator election:

---

[image]

---

I clicked on it and the election page was opened. I scrolled down and found the candidates and their posts, but I could not find a vote or upvote button. Here's a screenshot:

---

[image]

---

How does one cast his/her vote in this election?

Comment: "Drag and drop or click your selections in order of preference, with the most desirable candidate as first choice. You do not need to rank all candidates.

Unranked candidates will not receive your vote."

Comment: @KevinB Is this a new system? I remember in the past one would tick the upvote button

Comment: What you're remembering is the primary, we don't have enough candidates for a primary.

Comment: it is still a new system, sort of. The election page got an overhaul a while back (though we've had at least one election on SO after that overhaul), so the exact vote method is relatively new.

Comment: The drag and drop is the last change done to the voting three years ago: [Moderator Elections functionality: voting UI, commenting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361979).

Comment: and... please take time to read through the canditates questionaire. Don't base your vote(s) on the canditates score (only)

Comment: @Vickel Yeah, I don't look from one angle only. Sure

Comment: I think the confusing part for me is that once you drag candidates into the ranking box, it's presumably autosaved and you don't need to take action to cast your vote, which I guess will be autosubmitted when the voting period expires.

Comment: click also the "Learn More" button

Comment: @ggorlen There is actually a message above the list which states when the change will be auto-saved (although I should say "for me", one cannot simply generalize on this site). It counts down for 5 seconds. Which is in itself, pretty unorthodox. Can't think of any other site feature which does that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On the right side of the election page you would find the ballot:

[image: The election page with the voting selection on the right.]

The instructions read:

> Drag and drop or click your selections in order of preference, with the most desirable candidate as first choice. You do not need to rank all candidates.
>
> Unranked candidates will not receive your vote.

You can vote for any number of the candidates by dragging them to the box just above the list. Do make sure the order reflects your preference as your first choice will receive the highest weight of your vote, and the rest of the list will be in decreasing power.

You do not need to submit the vote. The list of candidates you have voted for and their order is automatically saved. You are free to revise your vote at any point until the end of the election. At that point whatever the state of your vote is will be taken and the all the votes counted.

You can "remove" a voted candidate by either:

- Dragging a candidate down from the ordered list to below it
- Click the "x" button next to the candidate's entry
- Click "clear all" under the last nominee you have ranked which will reset this in the initial position

You do not have to rank all candidates if you do not wish. Not ranking for a candidate will count your vote differently to if you placed them last.

The election uses single transferable vote (STV). For details how this works see:

- [OpaVote](https://www.opavote.com/methods/single-transferable-vote)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote)

Comment: Good! But what is about the mobile version?